# MYSQL Delete statement not working with Java Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have a web page which allows the user to enter a word and when that word is submitted, it will be deleted from the mysql database. The problem however is that the statement is not being executed.

My form:

```
<form id="rem1" action="removeGER" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="wordToRemoveGER" placeholder="Entry (GER)">
        <input type="submit" id="removeBtnGER" value="Remove Entry">
 </form>
```

My servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "removeGER", urlPatterns = {"/removeGER"})
public class removeGER extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String wordGER = request.getParameter("wordToRemoveGER");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Remove Word</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        // Database Checking Area
        SimpleDataSource.init("/database.properties");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        //ResultSet result = 
        stat.executeQuery(" DELETE FROM `word` WHERE `word` = \""+wordGER+"\"");
        out.println("<h2>You have successfully removed the word " + wordGER + "!</h2>");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(removeID.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}

}
```

I know that the String is correctly being retrieved from the form, and I know that the try block is being executed. The problem seems to be with the mysql statement itself.

Comment: You can only use one query per `executeQuery()`-command. You have two (`SET` and `DELETE` command).

Comment: You have successfully created a possible *SQL Injection*! You should use prepared statements..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use

```
    executeUpdate('')
```

instead of

```
    executeQuery('')
```

You should also make sure that you close the statement, and connection when you are finished with them

Comment: I did try using executeUpdate instead of executeQuery before but it didn't work, but is now working.

Comment: @hjalpmig it is because now you're using a single statement.

Answer (score 4):

You have the following issues:

1. You're executing multiple statements and probably your connection doesn't allow it.
2. When you execute multiple statements, you should use [`Statement#execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-), not `Statement#executeUpdate`.
3. If you need to pass arguments to your query, don't append it directly in your sql, this is cause of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Use `PreparedStatement` instead.

In order to do this, make sure your connection allows the execution of multiple statements by adding this parameter into your connection URL: `allowMultiQueries=true`

Example of how the connnection URL should look:

```
jdbc:mysql://<server>:<port>/<database>?allowMultiQueries=true
```

How the code will look like if you use `PreparedStatement`:

```
conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
String sql = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; DELETE FROM `word` WHERE `word` = ?";
PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stat.setString(1, wordGER);
stat.execute();
```

---

Now that you use a single delete statement, then you only need to use `PreparedStatement#executeUpdate` rather than `executeQuery`.

Comment: Also the fact that they're simply dumping an unsafe string directly into the query rather than using proper parameters

Comment: @JonK is right, especially because the statement already contains an SQL injection problem

Comment: Currently just trying to get the basics working before adding security measures.

Comment: I've just tested it locally to be sure, and parameters *do* work with `PreparedStatement#execute`

Comment: Thanks, I am now currently implementing prepared statements to protect against SQL injection